# i want sub form to find value based on combo box where primary key of two table is same

Tags: ms-access

I have a Goat Master table with Primary key `TagId` and another Table called WeightTable also with Primary key `TagId`

On the form called Mortalitydataentryform I am using a combobox/dropdown to populate the fields from the Goat Master Table.

I need to populate the subfom from the Weight table showing all the fields  based on same combobox/dropdown where the Goat ID is the same.  In other words, I need the subform to show the entries based on the id selected in the combobox.

Comment: The WeightTable is an Access table? Maybe should use Master/Child links of subform container control. Assuming these are not autonumber fields.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what subforms should do.

You main form's data source should contain the field `Goat ID` (from the *Goatmaster* table) and you subform's data source should contain the field `Goat ID` from the *WeightTable* table. In the properties of the subform control, there are two properties, *Link Child Fields* and *Link Master Fields*. Since both forms should be linked on just one field per form and on both sides the field is named `Goat ID`, both properties should be set to `Goat ID`.

The two properties can also be set using a wizard ("...").

`Goat ID` or `TagID`... you will know.